# Why doesnt res.json() and next() return a Promise<Promise<Thing>>

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Im currently learning asynchronous function in javascript and im confused as to why

Hello im quite new to javascript and i have a question on how Promises and then work
to my understanding the then returns a promise so

```
fetch(someApi)         
  .then((res)=>res.json())         
  .then((data)=>data)
```

my question is that since res.json() and then() both return a promise, why wouldnt the result of the 2nd line be a Promise<Promise>,

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation for `then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

> If the handler function:

...

> returns another pending promise: the fulfillment/rejection of the promise returned by then will be subsequent to the resolution/rejection of the promise returned by the handler. Also, the resolved value of the promise returned by then will be the same as the resolved value of the promise returned by the handler.

---

i.e. The callback function passed to the *second* `then` will receive the **resolved** value of the promise returned from the callback function passed to the **first** `then`.